# How to prevent CycleGAN from generating crossing lines? What restrictions should I add to the loss function?

Tags: neural-networks

I used CycleGAN to generate the images. During the model training phase, the input dataset (TrainA) and the ground truth (TrainB) are shown in the following figures (a) and (b). During the model testing phase, the model output is shown in figure (d).

My question is, there are no crossing lines in the training samples in Train B. Why are there crossing lines in the generated images (Test B)? How can I prevent CycleGAN from generating such crossing lines? What restrictions should I add to the loss function?[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi! I took the liberty of removing the "Python" tag from your question, as the underlying question is likely about modeling, and not really about programming in Python (which would be off-topic for this website). Theoretically, someone else could have the same question with a different language than Python, so an answer should be language-agnostic. I hope you'll get an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately your question has been closed. Personally, I disagree with this decision, but it is what it is. If you want your question to be reopened, I'd recommend to edit it to make it clear that you're looking for a solution regarding the correct way to model the problem you want to solve, without making reference to any particular programming language.